# Replace text stored in string

Tags: c#, itext

Using iText 5.5, I am trying to assign value from list to variable. Any professional eager to help amateur?

File I am parsing: https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf

Here is my code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PDF_file_reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> InvoiceNumbers = new List<string>();

            string filePath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.pdf";
            int pagesToScan = 2;

            string strText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pagesToScan; page++) //(int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++) <- for scanning all the pages in A PDF
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    strText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                    strText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strText)));
                    //creating the string array and storing the PDF line by line
                    string[] lines = strText.Split('\n');
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("Invoice Number"))
                        {
                            InvoiceNumbers.Add(line.Trim());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    var match = InvoiceNumbers.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains("Invoice Number"));

                    match.Replace("Invoice number", "").Trim();

                    Console.Write(match);

                    Console.Read();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need `match` to be `INV-3337` currently it seems to be `Invoice Number INV-3337`. Why this command:

`match.Replace("Invoice number", "").Trim();`?

does not perform Replace.

My output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the match is case sensitive (capital N vs lower case n).

```
match = match.Replace("Invoice Number", "").Trim();
```

Comment: Oh... how simple was that... That's why I have passion to coding, you have to pay attention to details... and sometimes another pair of eyes =) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing:

```
match.Replace("Invoice number", "").Trim();
```

use:

```
match = match.Replace("Invoice Number", "").Trim();
```